# ATtiny85 Breakout Board

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, pcb

I've made a PCB...
I'm not sure if it will work.
I've came here for some help.

I'd just like to know if there is anything obviously wrong with it.
I have attached a image of my PCB so can anyone please have a look.
I'm a complete newbie so don't go too hard on me.
[image]

Comment: Where is the schematic?

Comment: The top right thingy doesn't seem to do much. What is it anyway?

Comment: @jippie looks like a screw terminal for power

Comment: Your reset line from the ISP header is going to VCC, that's quite an obvious problem as it won't program. And the VCC is not connected on the header either.

Comment: @RSM that's what I thought, but it doesn't appear to be connected to the controller's Vcc.

Comment: @jippie - I see, I was looking at it on my phone and the colour of the traces and board look the same. It should protect it at least if something > 5V is put there ;)

Comment: What's with all the weird red blobs?  That circuit doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever.  Start from basics with a schematic and ask us about that. When the schematic is right you can look at converting it to a PCB layout.  And do your self a favour: Fritzing is NOT a good choice for making PCBs. It's fine for wiring diagrams for children to follow, but everyone else in the industry just laughs at you. Use a real EDA tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISP connector is wired wrong.

Pin 5, the reset pin is not connected to pin one of the ATTiny. This will hinder your ability to program the chip.

The 5 Volt from the header is also not connected to the IC.

I also hope you are not providing anything other than 5V through the screw terminal, as this will destroy the chip.

I would also move your electrolytic cap from the reset line and put the 0.1uf there if you want as the electrolytic will stop immediate resetting. Then move the electrolytic to the VCC of the chip.

Attached are some reference pics.

[image]
[image]